# How to distribute cron jobs to the cluster machines?

Tags: cron

I can install a new cron job using crontab command.
For example,

```
crontab -e
    0 0 * * * root rdate -s time.bora.net && clock -w > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now I have 100 machines in my cluster, I want to install the above cron task in all of the machines.

How to distribute cron jobs to the cluster machines?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: Ansible
Ansible can distribute machine configuration to remote machines. Please refer to:
https://www.ansible.com/

Method 2: Distributed Cron
You can use distribted cron to assign cron job. It has a master node and you can config your job easily and monitor the running result.
https://github.com/shunfei/cronsun

Answer (score 0):

crontab is stored `/var/spool/cron/(username)`

so, write your own cron jobs and distribute that location after acquire root permission.
  but if other user edit the crontab at the same time, you can never be sure when it will get changed.

below links help you

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173811
- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=144841
- https://serverfault.com/questions/347318/is-it-bad-to-edit-cron-file-manually

Answer (score 0):

Ansible already has a cron module:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/cron_module.html